# Как связать две папки в Linux

Tags: linux, сервер

На сервере есть две папки. Мне надо сделать так, чтобы первая папка не существовала как таковая, а являлась указателем на другую папку.
На машине работает сервер, и для двух доменов он создал две папки, один из доменов я хочу сделать зеркалом другого. Поскольку ни к каким конфигам у меня доступа нет, связать папки - единственный вариант

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/843740/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-in-a-linux-directory: `ln -s path/to/folder symlink_name`

Comment: andy.37, пробовал. После создания ссылки при cd открывается исходная папка. Да и сервер не отображает изменения

Comment: в том то и смысл ссылки

Comment: eri, говоря про исходную папку, я имел в виду, что ничего не поменялось. Как открывалась исходная, так она и продолжает открывать.

Comment: Попробуйте, для начала, удалить ту папку, которую Вы хотите сделать ссылкой. Сами думайте, сломаете Вы при этом все или нет.

Comment: andy.37, вроде сработало. Старую папку переименовал и после создания ссылки она заработала как надо. Кажется, изначальная проблема была в том, что папка с целевым названием уже существовала, и вместо того, чтобы создавать ссылку в текущей директории он создавал её в той папке. Спасибо, что помогли обратить на это внимание.